# ng2-smart-table create button not working correctly

Tags: angular, smart-table

I am getting data from firebase and displaying it with [`ng2-smart-table`](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table).

However, the add dialog doesn't close after I add the data. It's still opened with the values that were added.

Here's my code:

```ts
settings = {
    pager:{perPage:50},
    add: {
        addButtonContent: '<i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>',
        createButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
        cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
        confirmCreate: true,
    },
```

The function to create:

```ts
onCreateConfirm(event): any {
    //this service is updating the new data to firebase.
    this.service.createData(event.newData);
    //after that the newdata still on edit mode and not closing it...
}
```

Comment: Vitaly, I've tried my best to clarify what you requested in your question, but your grammar here doesn't make sense at all! Could you confirm that what I've just edited is correct?

Answer (score 6):

> Add this in your template html

```
     <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" 
(createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)"
(deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
(editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event)">
     </ng2-smart-table>
```

> Component

```
    settings = {delete: {
      confirmDelete: true
    },
    add: {
      confirmCreate: true
    },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true
    },
     .......
    }


  source: LocalDataSource;

  constructor() {
    this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data);
  }

  onDeleteConfirm(event):void {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      event.confirm.resolve(); 
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  onSaveConfirm(event):void {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to save?')) {
      event.newData['name'] += ' + added in code'; 
      event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  onCreateConfirm(event):void { 
      event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
  }
```

Comment: this isn't looks correct because its trigger onCreateConfirm once the user click on plus and should be trigger only after user fill all data

Comment: Old post used for custom add/edit/delete functionality

Comment: I don't think you right! you didn't read the post. the issue that it write to table 2 times one because it bund to firebase list and secont that you do resolve.

Answer (score 0):

you must add this line at the end of  onCreateConfirm(event)

```
event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
```

Comment: but this will add automatically to the table and also my function add this to firebase db, and then it will auto update the table for 2 instance one from firebase and other for resolve.

Comment: i can't understand your problem , can you give me more explanation

Comment: the issue is that I add this new data to firebase list. this list bind to the data source from table and then its get updated on the table, while after that if I will do your way it will update the table by it functionality and I will have 2 instanse, one is dummy result of resolve and other one by firebase list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on angularfire in combination with this table, I think its some kind of bug. 
I am testing the table too with AngularFire2 and I have the same issue. The only way to avoid this (homemade) is:

```
settings = {
    pager: {
        perPage: 1000
    }... // More settings, add, edit, actions, etc
```

When u edit and trigger the save button it reload all, BUT if the reloaded size + original size is lower than the pager.perPage limit u won´t see the duplicated things. This is my method:

```
    onEditConfirm(event): void {
    console.log(event.data); // Testing only
    console.log(event.newData); // Testing only
    this.af.database.object('Usuarios/' + 
    event.data.nif.toLowerCase()).set({
        email: event.data.email,
        nombre: event.newData.nombre,
        nif: event.data.nif,
        rol: event.data.rol
    });
    this.source.update(event.data, event.newData); //it update well
    event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
}
```

Now if we suppose we have 70 rows it will duplicate to 140, but if u have the pager.perPage property on a higher value u will not see the duplicated items. Tested. However it´s a bad solution, but I really think that it´s a bug of smarttables

Hope it helps 5 months later ^^"

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use

```
this.source = new LocalDataSource();
const data = this.service.getData();
this.source.load(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get the solution by trying many times and this code work for me

First, you read you data once by using firebase or angularfire2 for example

```
  this.user.take(1).subscribe(response => {
  response.forEach(item=>{
    this.data.push({
      id:this.i++,
      firstName: item.subs_name, 
      lastName: item.subs_info, 
      email: item.subs_price, 
      username: item.subs_storage
    });
  })
  this.source.load(this.data);
});
```

Second, you update the data in onSaveConfirm method

```
onSaveConfirm(event): void  {
 if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to make a changes?')) {
  event.confirm.resolve();
  this.database.object(`subscription/${event.newData.id}`).update({
    subs_name: event.newData.firstName, 
    subs_info: event.newData.lastName, 
    subs_price: event.newData.email, 
    subs_storage: event.newData.username
   })
  } else {
   event.confirm.reject();
  }
}
```

By doing like this in the system will show you the dummy data while if you make a changes it will save in you firebase

It's work for me i hope it will work for you too